# rsync between two windows server in different vlan via an ubuntu

Tags: networking, mount, windows, rsync, shared-folders

I was asked to sync two folders in two windows servers which are in two  different vlans . and for the sake of security these servers should not ping each other but an ubuntu machine can be in both vlans . I want to know is there a way to sync a those two folders with rsync ? or any other possible solution ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the Ubuntu box has two NICs then connect each one directly to a switch port configured as an access port to one VLAN and connect the other to another access port to the other VLAN and configure normally … But, if one NIC then connect it to a switch port configured as trunk and follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan

Comment: Your issue is with networking and not rsync

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.
But it's not clear to me exactly what are you asking for?
For different ways to do this ?

Can you clarify in your question:

- Can each windows server rsync to the linux machine?
- Can the linux machine rsync from/to each windows server?

Simplest solution I think: in a cron job on linux server

1. rsync from windows server 1 to local folder
2. rsync from local folder to windows server 2
3. rsync from windows server 2 to local folder
4. rsync from local folder to windows server 1

Note on rsync args to use.
Good default:
rsync -avz # -a archive mode, -v verbosity, -z compression
RTFM is good also ;) https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync